# TypeError: tableData.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, map-function

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function RenderTable(){
    const [tableData, updateTableData] = useState([{id: 1, name: "name", price: 200, size: "size"}]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch("/api/ManageSite").then(value => updateTableData(value.json()));
    }, []);

    return(
        <table>
            <tbody>
                {tableData.map(value =>
                    <tr key={value.id}>
                        <td>{value.name}</td>
                        <td>{value.price}</td>
                        <td>{value.size}</td>
                    </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
```

this error occurs, when I use map function in `return()`, but if I will do the same map function in `useEffect()`, it will work just fine, please explain why?

Comment: [Response.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) returns a Promise. Try `fetch("/api/ManageSite").then(r => r.json()).then(updateTableData)`. This is just a simple _typo_ question and should be closed

Comment: Can you post , what `updateTableData` looks like

Comment: @Kuncheria it's the setter returned by `useState()`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: api not returing values in Array format

Comment: The response body of your fetch is `ReadableStream<Uint8Array>`. Is this what you are expecting. From my understanding you are expecting an array of items similar to `{id: 1, name: "name", price: 200, size: "size"}`

Answer (score 0):

This could happen because is trying to map an object and not an array, so it is saying that doesn't exists the function Object.map().

First, ensure that the new state is an array.

Then, if can get results different from an aray, when rendering, to not have any page crash, ensure that is making a map on an array

```
{Array.isArray(tableData) && tableData.map(()=>{})
```

Answer (score -1):

`.json()` returns a promise, which means in ES6 you need to use another `then`.
Make sure the response from backend is array in JSON format.
Then you can just:

```
useEffect(()=>{
        fetch("/api/ManageSite")
          .then(value => value.json())
          .then(data => updateTableData(data))
    }, []);
```

Because no matter what even if you do fetch and update data like I did correctly but your endpoint response is not an array. Same error will keep occurring